# How to store rich text data in MongoDB and CouchDB from Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, couchdb, nosql

I am working with mongoDb and couchDb with node JS.
 The problem I am facing is how to store rich-text content like HTML data in a key-value pair. 
 I could not find much help on the Internet beside encoding data using URI encoding which would be one method.
Is their any built-in methods to encode rich-text or blob data for those database engines?

Comment: You mean besides `JSON.stringify()`? I guess we need some example data to be able to fully answer your question.

Comment: CouchDB supports [binary attachments](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Attachments), although as already said, we don't really have enough data to really provide much help.

Comment: Given that HTML is a string, you can probably just stick it in the document. Something like {"body" : "<html>....</html>"}

Comment: I have same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275599/how-do-i-insert-html-into-mongodb I read that "It's perfectly fine to store html files in MongoDB as standard utf-8 encoded strings." But I'm yet to understand how to do this. Maybe with javascript Encoder?

Answer (score 1):

When using CouchDB I would use attachments. You can read further [here](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#Standalone_Attachments)