# How do I insert HTML into Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I keep getting kicked out of the shell when I try to paste in an HTML text file. How can this be done? Do I first need to use some javascript to encode it or something?

Example:

```
db.test.insert({x:"<div id='product-description'><p>Who hasn’t wished for a mini-Roomba to    handle the arduous task of cleaning their iPhone screen? Now your dreams have come true!</p>  <p>See the Takara web page for a <a href='http://www.takaratomy.co.jp/products/automee/'  title='automee s' target='_blank'>demo video.</a></p>
<p><strong>Colors: </strong> White, Red, Orange and Blue<br>
Runs on a single AA battery.</p>
<p>1,575 yen</p><!-- end #product-description --></div>"})
```

**EDIT**

I put only single quotes inside my html and wrapped the whole thing in double-quotes, but still no good. shell error:

```
> j = ({z:"<div id='product-description'><p>Who hasn
---
Unicode text could not be correctly displayed.
Please change your console font to a Unicode font (e.g. Lucida Console).
---

â€™
bye
```

Comment: As the formatting of this question clearly shows, you need to escape HTML entities...

Comment: I only have one pair of double quotes! I thought that might fix it, but no. What do I need to escape and how? Is there some standard function?

Comment: Use base64 encoding/decoding if you don't want to care about quoting issues at all.

Comment: I read that "It's perfectly fine to store html files in MongoDB as standard utf-8 encoded strings." But I still can't find any way to actually do that. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/0m8KJ7mPWiQ/n_Gx2qf1-TEJ

Comment: Make sure there aren't any line breaks in the quoted string you're pasting into the shell. It won't work if there are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove or encode the control characters in your string.

For example, paste your text in [here](http://coderstoolbox.net/string/), and encode to UTF-8 ECMAScript (which means javascript strings).

ps: here an article about strings in javascript. tells you what needs escaping. http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch03_02.htm

Comment: This did not work for me. Essentially, the HTML is rendered as text out of mongo, not as HTML (example: I want <div>hi!</div> to render as "hi!" in an HTML div, but it renders as "<div>hi!</div>".

Answer (score 3):

**rompetroll** provided some good references to get started. I too found a good solution online which works fine:

[Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/#comment-83047)

But I think there is still some confusion regarding "displaying html back to browser from db". So, following are the steps which removes this confusion :

**Step 1: Store html in mongodb**

Mongo store everything in form of object. Basically **convert your html into utf-8 or ASCII complied string** and then store it to mongo.

```
<div>hi!</div> [from]

&lt;div&gt;hi!&lt;/div&gt; [to UTF-8]
```

**Step 2: Display html to browser**

This is the step which is the source of confusion to some. People often forget to convert string back to html before displaying it to browser.
You have to **decode your html using the same method you used for encoding**.

```
&lt;div&gt;hi!&lt;/div&gt; [output from mongo (decode it to html)]

<div>hi!</div> [browser output of above string]
```

(browser will read it as string and display as it is and not html(hi!) and hence needs to be decoded)

[Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/#comment-83047) that I have provided have reference for both the steps.

Hope this will help

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass), you don't need to encode. [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com/) editor also works, but you need a license.

Answer (score 0):

To add html through MongoDB console, you need to escape your string.
Use this: https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html#ad-output

#### Steps

- copy HTML
- go to the link above, paste HTML click on "Escape"
- copy the Escaped HTML
- Insert HTML (e.g: `db.Emails.updateMany({name: 'email/seller'}, {$set: {template: "<!DOCTYPE html\">\r\n<html lang=\"en\"> ..."}}`)