# Insert html file in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

**How to insert html tags within mongodb using nodejs**

I want to insert html files into mongodb using nodejs , how will be the code structure ?

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275599/how-do-i-insert-html-into-mongodb

Comment: Maybe you should try and have a look at the documentation first before asking a question without trying at all. https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/insert/

Comment: What do you mean by code structure? Could you elaborate with examples?

Answer (score 1):

use this one, example of get html code frm url and save into databse

```
 var mongoose = require("mongoose");
 var request = require('request');

 var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/SOF'; 

 // Create the database connection 
 mongoose.connect(dbURI); 

 // CONNECTION EVENTS
 // When successfully connected
 mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {  
 console.log('Mongoose default connection open to ' + dbURI);
 }); 

 // mongodb schema
 var dataschema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ofString:   String,
 })


 var model = mongoose.model("Data", dataschema); 
 var Data = mongoose.model("Data");
 var data = new  Data();

   /*
     i have used request node module to get html source code from url       and   insert into database
   */ 
 request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {     
       data.ofString = body;

      data.save(function(err, result) {
         if(err)
           console.log(err);
             else
            console.log(result);
       }); 
         }
       })

     // find data
     model.find({}, function(err, result) {
        if(err)
          console.log(err);
          else
         console.log(result);

         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store HTML parts and files in MonDOB as standard UTF-8 encoded strings, look through the documentation: [MongoDB Fundamentals](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/fundamentals/#when-should-i-use-gridfs), and [Insert Data with Node](https://docs.mongodb.com/getting-started/node/insert/)